# How To Use Python's argparse module to achieve the following?: scale_data.py [-h] (-t | -r [Number of Days Back]| -i [Start Date])

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to use Python's argparse module. My Python script named scale_data.py will require the use of 1 of 3 possible mutually exclusive switches:

```
scale_data.py -t

scale_data.py -r

scale_data.py -i
```

I have figured out how to make that happen using the "add_mutually_exclusive_group". My problem is that I want the -r switch or the -i switch to have OPTIONAL arguments after them:

```
scale_data.py -r 20

scale_data.py -i 02/01/2021
```

but the arguments are NOT required.

The help I assume would look this this:

```
scale_data.py [-h] (-t | -r [Number of Days Back]| -i [Start Date])
```

How is this done using the Python argparse module?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add your options to a mutually exclusive group.
2. Set `nargs` to `"?"` to allow zero or one arguments.
3. Set the `default` value to the optional-argument options to something that isn't `None`; I'm just constructing an unique sentinel object below. This is apparently required for the mutual exclusivity check to work with `"?"` nargs.

```
import argparse

NOTSET = object()


def main(argv):
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ag = ap.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    ag.add_argument("-t", action="store_true")
    ag.add_argument("-r", nargs="?", default=NOTSET)
    ag.add_argument("-i", nargs="?", default=NOTSET)
    print(ap.parse_args(argv))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(["-t"])
    main(["-r", "23"])
    main(["-i"])
    main(["-i", "8"])
    main(["-t", "-i", "8"])
```

This prints out

```
Namespace(t=True, r=<object>, i=<object>)
Namespace(t=False, r='23', i=<object>)
Namespace(t=False, r=<object>, i=None)
Namespace(t=False, r=<object>, i='8')
```

and finally a

```
error: argument -i: not allowed with argument -t
```

for the last test invocation.

Comment: Thank you so much! That pretty much did it! What I was doing wrong was having BOTH an 'action' and 'nargs' and that does not work. But the way you did it, I just changed the default to False for the swtiches with 'nargs'!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code I ended up creating with that answer from @AKX...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse


def main():
    scale_data_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Withings Scale Data, Process Data, Populate DB, Generate Graphs and Reports.')
    mutually_exclusive_group = scale_data_parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    mutually_exclusive_group.add_argument('-t', action='store_true', help='Fetch recent records then wait for trigger')
    mutually_exclusive_group.add_argument('-r', nargs='?', default=False, dest='Number Of Days Back', help='Fetch recent records then refresh all ouputs [Number Of Recent Days To Output (Int)]')
    mutually_exclusive_group.add_argument('-i', nargs='?', default=False, dest='Start Date', help='Fetech all records and completely reinitialize the database to the latest date as Start Date [Use This Start Date Instead (Date MM/DD/YYYY)]')
    scale_data_arguments = vars(scale_data_parser.parse_args())
    if scale_data_arguments['t']:
        print('(-t) Switch With No Arguments')
    elif scale_data_arguments['Number Of Days Back'] is None:
        print('(-r) Switch With No Arguments')
    elif scale_data_arguments['Number Of Days Back'] is not None and scale_data_arguments['Number Of Days Back'] is not False:
        print(f'(-r) Switch With An Argument ({scale_data_arguments["Number Of Days Back"]})')
    elif scale_data_arguments['Start Date'] is None:
        print('(-i) Switch With No Arguments')
    elif scale_data_arguments['Start Date'] is not None and scale_data_arguments['Start Date'] is not False:
        print(f'(-i) Switch With An Argument ({scale_data_arguments["Start Date"]})')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```